# Express.js serve static folder at specific url only

Tags: node.js, express

I have an existing express app I'm using for an API but I also want to deliver a folder with an HTML file and some images/css/js. I can get it to serve the HTML page but it does so at `/` while I only want it served at `/manual`. Here is my stripped down code with just `express.static`, my `/` route and the catch all redirect to `/`

```
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('manual'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.status(403);
  res.send('Access denied.');
  return;
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect(301, '/');
  return;
});
```

**What currently happens:** Going to `mysite.com/manual` redirects to `mysite.com/` which serves the `index.html` in the `manual` folder.

**What I want to happen:** Going to `mysite.com/manual` serves the `index.html` in the `manual` folder. And going to `mysite.com/` throws a 403 status code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Middleware/handlers are applied in the order you declare them, so you just need to change the order

```
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.status(403);
  res.send('Access denied.');
  return;
});

// adding a first parameter lets you apply the middleware to a route
app.use('/manual', express.static('manual'));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect(301, '/');
  return;
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. In this configuration, `/` gives access denied and `/manual` redirects to `/`

Comment: The update still doesn't work. `/manual` still redirects to `/`

Comment: Try an incognito window, browsers cache 301 redirects

Comment: (you should use 302 at least in dev)

Comment: Ah yes. It was a cache issue. The middleware can even go above the `/` route and still works. Thanks for the help!